# Problem when uninstall my application in vista and win7, but not in XP

Tags: windows-vista, installshield, uninstallation, installscript

I have a problem when uninstall my application in vista and win7, but not in XP. The error message is 
" The following error occured on the file 'C:\Windows\system32\mfc40.dll"
Access is denied.
(0x5)

I made installer for my application using installscript project in Installshield 2010
if i choose button ignore in that error message, my application can uninstall completed.
I cannot found solution for solve that problem.
So I try to find another idea,can I bypass that error message using script in installshield, so when get that error,system will ignore that message automatically or the message doesn't appear? Can anyone help me about the script?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a UAC issue - you need special permissions to access files in system32.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Visage.
Yes, I think so. But do you know how to give special permissions to access files in system32 through installscript or whatever? 
or at least to make that message doesn't appear while uninstalling?